# About using very small number in proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image: 9.5]
[image: 9.5 proof]
[image: example 6]
  I understand the proof, but the use of m in the proof seems unnecessary. In the discussion it say we don't want |$s_n$| to be small, hence we use m. But m is the greatest lower bound of |$s_n$|. So what difference does it make?
   Also, if I use |$s_n$| instead of m, will the proof be wrong?

Comment: The point is that if somehow $|s_n|$ got too small then $\frac{|s-s_n|}{|s_n s|}$ might not be small even though $|s-s_n|$ is small and $|s|$ is not small. You could write $\inf |s_n|$ instead of $m$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary, since you want to bound $$\left|\frac{1}{s_n} - \frac{1}{s}\right|$$ by a constant which does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

It won’t be a proof. You need to show that there is some *fixed* positive number $\alpha$ such that $|s_ns|\ge\alpha$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so that you can show that

$$\frac{|s-s_n|}{|s_ns|}\le\frac{|s-s_n|}\alpha$$

for all sufficiently large $n$. Then you can argue that by taking $n$ large enough, we can guarantee that $|s-s_n|<\alpha\epsilon$ and hence that

$$\left|\frac1{s_n}-\frac1s\right|=\frac{|s-s_n|}{|s_ns|}\le\frac{|s-s_n|}\alpha<\frac{\alpha\epsilon}{\alpha}=\epsilon$$

for all sufficiently large $n$. Until you establish that such an $\alpha$ exists, it could be that $|s_ns|$ decreases so fast with $n$ that the ratio $\frac{|s-s_n|}{|s_ns|}$ never gets less than $1$, say.

You do this by showing that the numbers $|s_n|$ have a positive infimum, which we’ll call $m$; then $|s_n|\ge m$ for all $n$, so $|s_ns|\ge m|s|$ for all $n$, and we can take $\alpha=m|s|$ (or any smaller positive number): then $|s_ns|\ge\alpha$ for all $n$.